# Reloading the current module when unittesting

Tags: python, unit-testing

When running a simple unittest it would sometimes be easier to be able to keep the tests inside the class. However, I don't know how to reload the current module, and so whenever that's needed I have to move the tests into a separate module. Is there a way around this?

```
module: foo
import unittest

class MyObject
...

class MockMyObject
...

class TestMock(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        MyObject = MockMyObject
        mocked = MyObject()

    def tearDown(self):
        reload(foo) # what goes here?

    def testFunction(self):
        mocked.do_mocked_function()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The way I've found to handle this is to `import sys` and `reload(sys.modules[__name__])` in the `tearDown` method, but I'm wondering if there is a better method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your original class in a variable and restore it in the `tearDown` function.
Here is an example:

```
class TestMock(unittest.TestCase):

    original = MyObject

    def setUp(self):
        global MyObject
        MyObject = MockMyObject

    def tearDown(self):
        global MyObject
        MyObject = TestMock.original

    def testFunction(self):
        MyObject().do_mocked_function()
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. And for pointing out the `global` part.

Answer (score 1):

that's not a good idea to reload your module.

```
class TestMock(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    MyObject = MockMyObject
    self.mocked = MyObject()

def tearDown(self):
    pass

def testFunction(self):
    self.mocked.do_mocked_function()
```

Comment: In this case the `tearDown` method isn't doing anything. And if I have more than one test then any patched changes to `MockMyObject` will persist between them which is what I'm trying to avoid by with `reload`.

Comment: every test case will execute the setUp method firstly, then there will be a brand new `self.mocked` object of MyObject.